# "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker, dbeaver

I created a docker-compose.yml file for Postgre and tried to connect to a database with DBeaver. I also tried to create a container for pdadmin and I got an error incorrect username or password when I tried to connect on localhost. I already tried and debug with this article: https://medium.com/@vinjenks/dockerized-local-postgres-and-scram-authentication-a-quick-fix-21c432951bd but it's not working.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: public
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_db:
    driver: local
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you change the Database to **public** as you specified in your docker-compose.yml file? Ideally, the DB schema should be public and not the actual DB itself. But modify your Dbeaver Database and let’s see what happens.

Comment: What messages do you see in the containers log, both when it is staring up, and when the password is failing?